# Previously working console app cannot update table in SQL Server after moving to new server

Tags: asp.net, windows, sql-server-2008-r2

I just had to migrate a console app written by a previous developer to another server.  It is supposed to update a table in a database that was migrated to the server at the same time.  The app was working fine on the previous server, but does not update the table in the database on the new server.

I added a check in the app to make sure there wasn't an issue with the connectionstring and got no error.  I have tried using Windows Authentication in the connectionstring and also setting up SQL Server Authentication and using that.  I can also log into SQL Server directly with both sets of credentials.

I'm thinking it might be a permissions issue on the new server.  Does anyone have any tips for how I can troubleshoot or resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you have application code, then check for hidden exceptions (empty catch block). It may be the reason that the exception is not handled by developer.